# How to find a subset of names in another column?

Tags: r

I have a list of file names that look like this:

```
files$name <-c("RePEc.aad.ejbejj.v.1.y.2010.i.0.p.84.pdf", "RePEc.aad.ejbejj.v.12.y.2017.i.2.p.1117.pdf", "RePEc.aad.ejbejj.v.2.y.2011.i.0.p.17.20.pdf", "RePEc.aad.ejbejj.v.2.y.2011.i.0.p.60.62.pdf")
```

I have a much longer list of IDs, which is a column of a larger dataframe, some of which correspond to the list of file names (`names`) but these names have different puncutation. The column looks like this:

```
df$repec_id <- c("RePEc:aad.ejbejj:v:1:y:2010:i:0:p:84", "RePEc:aad:ejbejj:v:12:y.2017:i:2:p:1117", "RePEc:aad:ejbejj:v:2:y:2011:i:0:p:17-20", "RePEc:aad:ejbejj:v:2:y:2011:i:0:p:60-62", "RePEc:aad.ejbejj:v:1:y:2010:i:0:p:99","RePEc:aad.ejbejj:v:1:y:2010:i:0:p:103")
```

I want to subset the list in `df$repec_id` so that I have only the strings that correspond to file names in `files$name` but they have different punctuation. In other words, I want an output that looks like this:

```
ID_subset <- c("RePEc:aad.ejbejj:v:1:y:2010:i:0:p:84", "RePEc:aad:ejbejj:v:12:y.2017:i:2:p:1117", "RePEc:aad:ejbejj:v:2:y:2011:i:0:p:17-20", "RePEc:aad:ejbejj:v:2:y:2011:i:0:p:60-62")
```

Initially, I thought that removing all the special characters from both lists and then comparing them would work. So I did this:

```
files$name <- str_replace_all(files$name, "\\.pdf", "")
files$name <- str_replace_all(files$name, "[[:punct:]]", "")
df$repec_id <- str_replace_all(files$name, "[[:punct:]]", "")
subset <- df[trimws(df$repec_id) %in% trimws(files$name), ]
```

However, I need a way of preserving the original structure of the IDs in `df$repec_id` because I need to provide a list of IDs from `df$repec_id` that are/ are not in the subset. Does anyone have any suggestions? Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use

```
!gsub('[^[:alnum:]]+', '', df$repec_id) %in% gsub('\\.pdf$|[^[:alnum:]]', '',files$name)
#[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

You can remove all punctuations from  `repec_id` and `name` and use `%in%` to find out the strings that match.

```
gsub('[[:punct:]]', '', df$repec_id) %in% 
          gsub('\\.pdf$|[[:punct:]]', '',files$name) 
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

If you add negation(`!`) sign to this you would get strings that do not match.

```
!gsub('[[:punct:]]', '', df$repec_id) %in% 
       gsub('\\.pdf$|[[:punct:]]', '',files$name) 
#[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

This maintains the length same as `df$repec_id` so you can use this to subset rows from `df`.

Comment: Can I just confirm that it's the other way round? I want to find out which of the files$name values are in df$repec_id so I would write, for example, 
gsub('[[:punct:]]', '',files$name) %in% gsub('\\.pdf$|[[:punct:]]', '',df$repec_id)

Comment: yes, in general, `%in%` will return output of length of LHS.